# VSCode — Commit custom snippets to repository

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

How do I share my custom snippets with my colleagues through a repository? For example, sharing a `javascript.json` file.

I know it should go inside `.vscode`, but where exactly and with what exact config?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the workspace `.vscode` folder create a file with extension `.code-snippets` and place your snippets inside. You can add a `scope` to limit the snippet to languages

**`.vscode/custom.code-snippets`**

```
{
    // Place your workspace snippets here. Each snippet is defined under a snippet name and has a scope, prefix, body and 
    // description. Add comma separated ids of the languages where the snippet is applicable in the scope field. If scope 
    // is left empty or omitted, the snippet gets applied to all languages. The prefix is what is 
    // used to trigger the snippet and the body will be expanded and inserted. Possible variables are: 
    // $1, $2 for tab stops, $0 for the final cursor position, and ${1:label}, ${2:another} for placeholders. 
    // Placeholders with the same ids are connected.
    // Example:
    // "Print to console": {
    //  "scope": "javascript,typescript",
    //  "prefix": "log",
    //  "body": [
    //      "console.log('$1');",
    //      "$2"
    //  ],
    //  "description": "Log output to console"
    // }
"Print to console": {
    "scope": "javascript,typescript",
    "prefix": "log",
    "body": [
      "console.log('$1');",
      "$2"
    ],
    "description": "Log output to console"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! After some more research based on your answer, I found the official docs: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_project-snippet-scope